# Jasper API Call returning 500 error for larger reports in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, jasperserver

I am using Larevel (PHP Framework) and have integrated Jasper API for reporting. It is working for small reports which usually takes less that 60 seconds to process. But jasper throws 500 Internal error for large reports which usually takes 2-3 minutes processing time to laravel. When I run same report on Jasper panel it works but it throws an error (code 500) to Laravel from API Call.

**PHP settings :-  memory_limit : 512M,    post_max_size : 400M,    upload_max_filesize : 300M,    max_execution_time : 600**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url+'admin/get-report-details',
                data:   $('form#jsperReports').serialize(), 
                dataType:'json',
                timeout:1200000, 
                beforeSend: function(){ 
                    $('#reportDetailsRow').addClass('hide');
                    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
                        message: '<p class="text-center">Please wait while we do something...</p>',
                        closeButton: false
                    });
                },
                success:function(data){ 
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    if(!!data && data.success == true){
                            $('#reportDetails').html(data.html);
                            $('#reportDetailsRow').removeClass('hide');
                    }else if (!!data && data.success == false) {
                        showMsgModel("Error",data.msg)
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Laravel Code:**

```
$JASPERSETTINGS= \App\JASPERSETTINGS::find(Input::get('report_name'));
        if(!$JASPERSETTINGS){return response()->json( array('success' => false,'msg'=>"Settings Not Found.") );}
        $c = new Client("http://".env('JSPER_IP')."/jasperserver", env('JSPER_ID'), env('JSPER_PWD'));
        $input_controls = $c->reportService()->getReportInputControls('/'.$JASPERSETTINGS->folder_path);
        $parameter= \App\JASPERPARAMETER::where('jsaper_id','=',$JASPERSETTINGS->id)->where('parameter_dy','!=','')->pluck('parameter_dy_query','jasper_parameter')->toArray();
        foreach($input_controls as $ic) {
            if(array_key_exists($ic->id,$parameter)){
                $sqlQuery=$parameter[$ic->id];
                if(preg_match_all('/{+(.*?)}/', $parameter[$ic->id], $m)) {
                    $matches=array_unique(($m[1]));
                }
                if(count($matches)>0){
                    $rt=0;
                    foreach($matches as $k=>$value){
                        if(strpos($parameter[$ic->id], '{'.$value.'}') !== false){
                            $PVALUE= \App\JASPERPARAMETER::where('jsaper_id','=',$JASPERSETTINGS->id)->where('jasper_parameter','=',$ic->id)->where('parameter_dy','!=','')->first();
                            $par= explode(',',$PVALUE->parameter_dy);
                            if(count($par)>0 && isset($par[$rt]))
                            $sqlQuery = str_replace('{'.$value.'}',"'".Input::get($par[$rt])."'", $sqlQuery);
                            $rt++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $data=DB::select( DB::raw($sqlQuery));
                $ff=$ic->id;
                $options[$ic->id]= $data[0]->$ff;
            }else{
                $rules[$ic->id] = 'Required';
                $options[$ic->id]=Input::get($ic->id);
            }
        }   
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::get(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            return response()->json($messages);
        }
        $time= \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_His');
        $filename=str_replace(" ","_",$JASPERSETTINGS->file_name).'_'.$time.'.'.Input::get('report_type');
        if($JASPERSETTINGS->dy_file_name!='n'){
            #to Make Dynamic Report Name
            $getType= \App\JASPERPARAMETER::where('jsaper_id','=',$JASPERSETTINGS->id)->where('jasper_parameter','=',$JASPERSETTINGS->dy_file_name)->first();
            $this->QUERY_TYPE= array('1'=>'Input','2'=>'Drop Down','3'=>"Date",'4'=>"Date Time Range");
            if($getType && $getType->jasper_parameter_type==1){
                $filename=str_replace(" ","_",Input::get($JASPERSETTINGS->dy_file_name)).'_'.$time.'.'.Input::get('report_type');
            }else if($getType && $getType->jasper_parameter_type==2){
                $data= DB::select( DB::raw(Input::get('SQL_QUERY'))." LIMIT 1");
                if(count($data)>0 && isset($data[$JASPERSETTINGS->dy_file_name])  && !empty($data[$JASPERSETTINGS->dy_file_name])){
                    $filename=str_replace(" ","_",$data[$JASPERSETTINGS->dy_file_name]).'_'.$time.'.'.Input::get('report_type');
                }
            }
        }
        $report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/'.$JASPERSETTINGS->folder_path, Input::get('report_type'), null, null, $options);
        if(Input::get('report_type')=="html"){
            $returnHTML= view('report/jasper-report-details')->with(compact('report'))->render();
            return response()->json( array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML) );
        }elseif(Input::get('report_type')=="pdf"){
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($report));
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            echo $report;
        }elseif(Input::get('report_type')=="xls" || Input::get('report_type')=="xlsx"|| Input::get('report_type')=="csv"){
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            echo $report;
        }else{
            return response()->json( array('success' => false,'msg'=>"Working For This.") );
        }
```

**Below is server logs**

**Jasper server log:**
2018-02-01 10:06:15,794 ERROR RenderViewExceptionInterceptor,ajp-apr-8009-exec-11:58 - Internal server error occurred. Please contact your system administrator.
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

2018-02-01 10:06:15,807 ERROR HandlerExecutionChain,ajp-apr-8009-exec-11:173 - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

**Tomcat log:**
01-Feb-2018 10:06:15.793 SEVERE [ajp-apr-8009-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

01-Feb-2018 10:06:15.836 SEVERE [ajp-apr-8009-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jasperserver] in context with path [/jasperserver] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed] with root cause

**localhost_access_log:**
[01/Feb/2018:14:48:54 +0000] "GET /jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/MYPROJ/TR_MYPROJ/TR.pdf?interactive=true&onePagePerSheet=false&freshData=true&saveDataSnapshot=false&course_name=%27TR00000017%27%2C%27TR00000046%27 HTTP/1.1" 500 -

**Am I missing any configuration or do I need to do any other setting while making API Call to Jasper from Laravel?**

Comment: pzl provide the LAravel code

Comment: It could be that `maximum execution time` for your PHP causing the process to abort?

Comment: Is it question about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: Laravel code is updated. Please have a look.

Comment: Your code looks BAD. With all those preg matches, array functions etc sure you exhaust server memory, so this has nothing to do with laravel. Has to do more with php and server memory usage. Your code its so bad that it needs more memory to work. So change php.ini memory limit set it to greater than what you have.